Input/Output error upload with arduino-cli / avrdude
Unpacked my first Arduino today, an Uno. Went to try the instructions from the arduino-cli getting started tutorial.
When I connect the unit with USB, I get three quick flashes, then slow continual flash on L. ON is green and static on.
When uploading, I get:
$ ./arduino-cli upload -v -p/dev/ttyACM0 --fqbn arduino:avr:uno --log-level trace --log /home/lash/src/tests/arduino/first

[...]

TRAC[0000] Executing upload tool: "/home/lash/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-C/home/lash/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega328p -carduino "-P/dev/ttyACM0" -b115200 -D "-Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino/sketches/DEB5FC46AAF7CC866DBCF1FB0E7F766A/first.ino.hex:i"  phase=upload
"/home/lash/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-C/home/lash/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega328p -carduino "-P/dev/ttyACM0" -b115200 -D "-Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino/sketches/DEB5FC46AAF7CC866DBCF1FB0E7F766A/first.ino.hex:i"

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/lash/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/lash/.avrduderc"

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Input/output error

avrdude done.  Thank you.

ERRO[0010] Upload port detection failed, watcher closed  task=port_detection
DEBU[0010] Received message type: remove, port: /dev/ttyACM0  discovery="builtin:serial-discovery"
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1


Full log here: https://g33k.holbrook.no/86ce60598e75aad78d57cb5c3dc779a58dfda580f8b815f1fdc304601b6a4c52
Seems correctly identified by kernel:
[458984.503600] usb 3-2.1.3: USB disconnect, device number 31
[458985.992061] usb 3-2.1.3: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[458986.090224] usb 3-2.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
[458986.090229] usb 3-2.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[458986.090231] usb 3-2.1.3: Product: Arduino Uno
[458986.090232] usb 3-2.1.3: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[458986.090233] usb 3-2.1.3: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[458986.099511] cdc_acm 3-2.1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

Have write permission:
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/01-ttyusb.rules 
SUBSYSTEMS=="tty", TAG+="uaccess", MODE="0666"
$ groups lash
tty uucp lash
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root uucp 166, 0 Oct 14 03:58 /dev/ttyACM0

Consulted arduino archlinux wiki page, which implied the following command that also doesn't work:
$ stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 cs8 115200 ignbrk -brkint -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts
stty: /dev/ttyACM0: Input/output error

Any tips on how I can troubleshoot this further?

archlinux 6.10.10
arduino-cli 1.0.3 (archlinux package) and 1.0.4 (built from go source)


https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v1/tutorials/Linux/#please-read

not helpful. this is not a permission issue, it is clearly stated in the question that I have permission to write, and the error doesn't even match. @Juraj
